# 2008 Ford Focus Starting Problem

Tags: ford, starting, focus, ignition-switch

I have a 2008 Ford Focus, and sometimes it starts, and sometimes it doesn't.  I have replaced the battery, starter, relay and ignition switch.  It happens more in the summer than winter, it doesn't make a sound when you turn the key but the lights and everything on the dash come on.  With jumper cables it will start right up.  What could the problem be?

Comment: Sounds like a possible voltage drop issue/high resistance in the wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Look for corrosion at your battery cables and especially at the starter connection, and all electrical grounds. Clean off the corrosion with a steel brush if you can, replace the ends and lengths of wires if the corrosion is too invasive.